# PostgreSQL operations between two dates

Tags: postgresql

I have the following operation in postgreSQL to do, I need it to either return true or false

```
2019-08-21 19:00:00+03 - 2019-08-21 19:06:29.642+03 / 3600::numeric > 0
```

I tried this

```
EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM 2019-08-21 19:00:00+03 - 2019-08-21 19:00:00+03 - 2019-08-21 19:06:29+03)::numeric / 3600::numeric > 0))
```

to no avail, also

```
(2019-08-21 19:00:00+03 - 2019-08-21 19:06:29.642+03)::numeric / 3600::numeric > 0
```

doesn't work either. Anyone has any idea? (We can get rid of the +03 at the end if needed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an interval:

```sql
timestamptz '2019-08-21 19:06:29.642+03' - timestamptz '2019-08-21 19:00:00+03' > interval '0 seconds'
```

Note that the order for the minus is important (because there is no built-in `abs()` method for intervals).

If you can't guarantee the order, you could test for "not equals":

```sql
timestamptz '2019-08-21 19:00:00+03' - timestamptz '2019-08-21 19:06:29.642+03' <> interval '0 seconds'
```

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe yup, from the docs: _The SQL standard requires that writing just timestamp be equivalent to timestamp without time zone, and PostgreSQL honors that behavior. (**Releases prior to 7.3 treated it as timestamp with time zone**.) timestamptz is accepted as an abbreviation for timestamp with time zone; this is a PostgreSQL extension._

Comment: @Chris: see my update. The order of the values matters (bigger - smaller)

Comment: So, i get a syntax error for either timestamp or timestamptz

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yeah, but i need to divide it to 3600, that's where it throws the error

Comment: @Chris: why do you think you need that? The difference between two timestamps is an interval and you can compare that with an interval of length 0

Comment: I need to check something, that's why; that's what i'm having most of the trouble with..

Comment: @Chris: If you need to check something else than you *asked*, then you've asked the wrong question and cannot blame a correct answer for it.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with, for anyone wondering.

`select extract(epoch from timestamp '2019-08-21 19:00:00' - timestamp '2019-08-21 19:06:29') / 3600::numeric`